How to solve "Redeclaration of port 'logic' is not allowed" error while synthesizing SystemVerilog code in dc shell?
I am very new to SystemVerilog and am still learning the syntax. I wrote this code for a graph convolutional network (GCN) module.
module gcn
#(
    parameter FEATURE_COLS = 96,
    parameter WEIGHT_ROWS = 96,
    parameter FEATURE_ROWS = 6,
    parameter WEIGHT_COLS = 3,
    parameter FEATURE_WIDTH = 5,
    parameter WEIGHT_WIDTH = 5,
    parameter DOT_PROD_WIDTH = 16,
    parameter ADDRESS_WIDTH = 13,
    parameter COUNTER_WEIGHT_WIDTH = $clog2(WEIGHT_COLS),
    parameter COUNTER_FEATURE_WIDTH = $clog2(FEATURE_ROWS),
    parameter MAX_ADDRESS_WIDTH = 2,
    parameter NUM_OF_NODES = 6,
    parameter COO_NUM_OF_COLS = 6,
    parameter COO_NUM_OF_ROWS = 2,
    parameter COO_BW = $clog2(COO_NUM_OF_COLS)
)
(
    input logic clk,
    input logic reset,
    input logic start,
    input logic [WEIGHT_WIDTH-1:0] data_in [WEIGHT_ROWS-1:0],
    input logic [COO_BW-1:0] coo_in [1:0], // Row 0 and Row 1
    output logic [COO_BW-1:0] coo_address,
    output logic [ADDRESS_WIDTH-1:0] read_address,
    output logic enable_read,
    output logic done,
    output logic [MAX_ADDRESS_WIDTH-1:0] max_addi_answer [FEATURE_ROWS-1:0]
);

    // Internal signals and registers
    logic [FEATURE_WIDTH-1:0] feature_matrix [FEATURE_ROWS-1:0][FEATURE_COLS-1:0];
    logic [WEIGHT_WIDTH-1:0] weight_matrix [WEIGHT_ROWS-1:0][WEIGHT_COLS-1:0];
    logic [DOT_PROD_WIDTH-1:0] result [FEATURE_ROWS-1:0][WEIGHT_COLS-1:0];
    logic [MAX_ADDRESS_WIDTH-1:0] argmax [FEATURE_ROWS-1:0];
    logic done_reg;

    // Pipelining and state management
    always_ff @(posedge clk or posedge reset) begin
        if (reset) begin
            done_reg <= 1'b0;
        end else if (start) begin
            // Perform feature transformation and aggregation
            // Placeholder logic: Replace with actual matrix-vector multiplication or aggregation logic
            done_reg <= 1'b1;
        end
    end

    // Assign outputs
    assign done = done_reg;
    assign max_addi_answer = argmax;

endmodule

I tried synthesizing the code with Design Compiler, but I keep getting these syntax errors:
################################################################################################# Read verilog files
analyze -format verilog $netlist_search_path/$netlist_name
Running PRESTO HDLC
Compiling source file /afs/asu.edu/users/z/m/a/zmanita/asap7_rundir/lab4/gcn/systemVerilog/verilog.sv
Error:  /afs/asu.edu/users/z/m/a/zmanita/asap7_rundir/lab4/gcn/systemVerilog/verilog.sv:22: Syntax error at or near token 'clk'. (VER-294)
Error:  /afs/asu.edu/users/z/m/a/zmanita/asap7_rundir/lab4/gcn/systemVerilog/verilog.sv:23: Redeclaration of port 'logic' is not allowed. (VER-121)
Error:  /afs/asu.edu/users/z/m/a/zmanita/asap7_rundir/lab4/gcn/systemVerilog/verilog.sv:23: Syntax error at or near token 'reset'. (VER-294)
Error:  /afs/asu.edu/users/z/m/a/zmanita/asap7_rundir/lab4/gcn/systemVerilog/verilog.sv:24: Redeclaration of port 'logic' is not allowed. (VER-121)
Error:  /afs/asu.edu/users/z/m/a/zmanita/asap7_rundir/lab4/gcn/systemVerilog/verilog.sv:24: Syntax error at or near token 'start'. (VER-294)
Error:  /afs/asu.edu/users/z/m/a/zmanita/asap7_rundir/lab4/gcn/systemVerilog/verilog.sv:25: Redeclaration of port 'logic' is not allowed. (VER-121)
Error:  /afs/asu.edu/users/z/m/a/zmanita/asap7_rundir/lab4/gcn/systemVerilog/verilog.sv:25: Syntax error at or near token 'data_in'. (VER-294)
Error:  /afs/asu.edu/users/z/m/a/zmanita/asap7_rundir/lab4/gcn/systemVerilog/verilog.sv:26: Redeclaration of port 'logic' is not allowed. (VER-121)
Error:  /afs/asu.edu/users/z/m/a/zmanita/asap7_rundir/lab4/gcn/systemVerilog/verilog.sv:26: Syntax error at or near token 'coo_in'. (VER-294)
Error:  /afs/asu.edu/users/z/m/a/zmanita/asap7_rundir/lab4/gcn/systemVerilog/verilog.sv:27: Redeclaration of port 'logic' is not allowed. (VER-121)
Error:  /afs/asu.edu/users/z/m/a/zmanita/asap7_rundir/lab4/gcn/systemVerilog/verilog.sv:27: Syntax error at or near token 'coo_address'. (VER-294)
Error:  /afs/asu.edu/users/z/m/a/zmanita/asap7_rundir/lab4/gcn/systemVerilog/verilog.sv:28: Redeclaration of port 'logic' is not allowed. (VER-121)
Error:  /afs/asu.edu/users/z/m/a/zmanita/asap7_rundir/lab4/gcn/systemVerilog/verilog.sv:28: Syntax error at or near token 'read_address'. (VER-294)
Error:  /afs/asu.edu/users/z/m/a/zmanita/asap7_rundir/lab4/gcn/systemVerilog/verilog.sv:29: Redeclaration of port 'logic' is not allowed. (VER-121)
Error:  /afs/asu.edu/users/z/m/a/zmanita/asap7_rundir/lab4/gcn/systemVerilog/verilog.sv:29: Syntax error at or near token 'enable_read'. (VER-294)
Error:  /afs/asu.edu/users/z/m/a/zmanita/asap7_rundir/lab4/gcn/systemVerilog/verilog.sv:30: Redeclaration of port 'logic' is not allowed. (VER-121)
Error:  /afs/asu.edu/users/z/m/a/zmanita/asap7_rundir/lab4/gcn/systemVerilog/verilog.sv:30: Syntax error at or near token 'done'. (VER-294)
Error:  /afs/asu.edu/users/z/m/a/zmanita/asap7_rundir/lab4/gcn/systemVerilog/verilog.sv:31: Redeclaration of port 'logic' is not allowed. (VER-121)
Error:  /afs/asu.edu/users/z/m/a/zmanita/asap7_rundir/lab4/gcn/systemVerilog/verilog.sv:31: Syntax error at or near token 'max_addi_answer'. (VER-294)
*** Presto compilation terminated with 19 errors. ***

What can I change in my code to fix this?

Remove the logic keyword from all of your port definitions should resolve the error, though it should not be necessary. Why the synthesis tool is mistaking the logic keyword for the port name, I don't know - what tool are you using? I wonder if it is compiling as Verilog rather than SystemVerilog

I am using Cadence Virtuoso to write the code, and dc_shell for the synthesis. Hope that answers your question.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

So the issue is that the synthesis tool is interpreting the keyword logic as the port name. As a result the actual name after it is seen as an unexpected token. Furthermore, every port then has the same name, so you get the redeclaration error.
This stems from the fact that logic was not a keyword in Verilog. It was introduced later on as a net type in SystemVerilog. As a result if you try and synthesise using a Verilog compiler it will cause this error. Looking at your command output:
analyze -format verilog $netlist_search_path/$netlist_name

You have specified the format as verilog, causing the Design Compiler to interpret the files as Verilog and not System Verilog.
If you instead use the following command it should work. sverilog is the System Verilog format.
analyze -format sverilog $netlist_search_path/$netlist_name

Alternatively, simply running the command without the -format argument should allow the tool to determine the language based on the file extension (.v for Verilog, .sv for SystemVerilog, .vhd for VHDL).
analyze $netlist_search_path/$netlist_name


This solved the issue. Thank you very much for your help!
